# How do I create new models not affecting the nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I already have a general idea of how it should be done. The only issue that I face now is how to actually send the data. I don't want to create new `Projects` I just want to add them to the notifications. How do I pass the data, the actual JSON?

```py
class NotificationsScheduleSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True) # Thats the Many2Many Field 
    user = HiddenField(default=CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = NotificationsSchedule
        fields = [
            "pk",
            "projects",
            "period",
            "week_day",
            "created_at",
            "time",
            "report_type",
            "user",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        breakpoint() # I don't ever get "projects" in validated_data just Empty OrderedDict
        projects_data = validated_data.pop("projects", [])
        notification = NotificationsSchedule.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return notification

class ProjectSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["pk", "name"]
```

I want to be able to pass something like this.

```
{
    "projects": [290, 289],
    "period": "daily",
    "week_day": 2,
    "time": "16:02:00",
    "report_type": "word_report"
}
```

But it expects dict instead.

```
"non_field_errors": [
                "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int."
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set read_only,

```
 projects = ProjectSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

And when creating Notifications ,

```
 notification = NotificationsSchedule.objects.create(**validated_data)
 notification.projects.add(*self.initial_data.get("projects"))
 notification.save()
```